# Do I need to do anything special to make WCF calls work over HTTPS, ..if HTTP works fine?

Tags: ajax, https, wcf, webhttpbinding

I have two versions of the same proof-of-concept site: The unsecure version:

http://www.tlsadmin.com/tlsadmin/PortalHome.aspx

and the secure version:

https://www.tlsadmin.com/tlsadmin/PortalHome.aspx

The problem I have is that my WCF-Based web services don't seem to work under HTTPS.  Is there something I'm missing, or not understanding about this?  I thought a relative URL for the SVC file would cover everything

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" >
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Services/Contacts.svc" />
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Services/Domains.svc" />
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Services/TreeViewNavigation.asmx" />
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="/Services/FullSoaSchedulerService.svc/json" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Perhaps I need to add an additional binding for the webservice to work over HTTPS?

```
<service name="LC.www.nexthop.mx.POC.grid_WebService.Domains">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="LC.www.nexthop.mx.POC.grid_WebService.DomainsAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="LC.www.nexthop.mx.POC.grid_WebService.Domains" />
      </service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add a custom binding to your configuration to enable it for HTTPS by setting your binding's security mode to transport.

```
 <bindings>
   <webHttpBinding>
     <binding name="httpsBinding">
       <security mode="Transport">
       </security>
     </binding>
   </webHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
```

The default security mode is `None` which doesn't play well with HTTPS.

Then assign that binding to your endpoint:

```
<service name="LC.www.nexthop.mx.POC.grid_WebService.Domains">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="LC.www.nexthop.mx.POC.grid_WebService.DomainsAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpsBinding" contract="LC.www.nexthop.mx.POC.grid_WebService.Domains" />
</service>
```

This [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2008/02/20/wcf-bindings-needed-for-https.aspx) helped me out when I first ran into this situation.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Yeah, that stumped me at first, too.  I wish it wasn't so unintuitive (it wasn't intuitive at all for me :) ).  The thing to keep in mind is that your development environment may not be HTTPS, so you'll need to change that security mode for DEV.  I have a build process that handles that (no security for DEV, Transport for QA/PROD).

Comment: wht if, I want to make this in both SSL and Non-SSL